# What font is this website using? (graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Tags: font-identification

I was wondering if you could tell me what font you are using on this site? I am currently looking for a new font for my company's brochures and I love this one - it's nice and clean, professional and yet has personality. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This question does not meet our [font identification requirements](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/2366) and I have voted to close it as such

Comment: I would recommend the plugin Fontface Ninja for Chrome, Firefox & Safari. When using, hover over any text on a website to see all of the text properties (font type, size, line height, etc).

Comment: Ironically, this would be on-topic on Meta.

Answer (score 4):

It's [Open Sans](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans).

In multiple browsers (eg. Firefox and Google Chrome) You can always <kbd>right-click</kbd> and choose 'Inspect Element' (or something to that effect) to inspect a website's CSS rules. Since typeface is set by CSS, you should be able to find a clue that way.

Comment: awesome - thank you for both the intel as well as the tip! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

Another good way to finding out what font a site uses is to use is Fount

Find it here : https://fount.artequalswork.com/

Check it out, its pretty neat.